# Akka: How is PersistenceQuery a replacement for PersistentView?

Tags: stream, akka, persistence, reactive-programming

We use [PersistentView](http://doc.akka.io/japi/akka/2.3.9/akka/persistence/PersistentView.html) in our code for a cluster singleton to ease the load on it coming from the read events. Now with `PersistentView` becoming deprecated, it is suggested we would use `PersistentQuery` which is based on the Stream API. We have:

> The consuming actor may be a plain Actor or a PersistentActor if it
>   needs to store its own state (e.g. fromSequenceNr offset). 
>   The corresponding query type is EventsByPersistenceId. There are
>   several alternatives for connecting the Source to an actor
>   corresponding to a previous PersistentView actor:

My questions are:

1. In `PersistentView`, the events were handled in the receive block and we had a push-based system. With `PersistentQuery`, each call to `EventsByPersistenceId`, etc. is like a pull. How would I emulate the continual `receive` behaviour in actors? Should I even do that? Is this really the way Streams are supposed to be used.
2. My understanding is that each call to get `EventsByPersistenceId` is essentially a query. is this therefore not inefficient to do these looped queries?
3. I would also be interested to know why `PersistentView` was dropped. was this a mere optimisation or is this part of Akka's wider move about migrating to streams and there is a paradigm shift? Am I making a mistake in trying to emulate the `PersistentView` behaviour with `PersistenceQuery`?
4. I have come across this [repo](https://github.com/ovotech/akka-persistence-query-view) which seems to provide the old `PersistentView` functionality while using `PersistenceQuery` behind the curtains. Would it be a good idea to use it based on the considerations in ^ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. As you mentioned, `eventsByPersistenceId` will give you an Akka Streams `Source`, so it's a bit unclear what you mean by "each call". You define a stream from this source and materialize it once, and new events will be emitted by it. You can, among other things, send them to the actor replacing your `PersistentView` with `mapAsync` and `ask`. This approach is explained on http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/persistence-query.html#materialize-view-using-mapasync and http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/stream/stream-integrations.html#mapasync-ask 
   So from your actor's point of view it's still "push-based" and handled by `receive`.
   Note that `mapAsync` takes a parallelism factor in the first parameter list. To process the events in the order they occur, you should set it to "1" (i.e. no parallelism). If you set it to a higher value, say *n*, the stream will take *n* events and send the messages to the actor in parallel, which means they will end up in the mailbox in random order.
2. Again, how do you mean "each call"? It may well be just one - you run/materialize the stream on startup and it will stream events indefinitely. The underlying journal plugin implementation will most likely use polling, that's correct. *(I don't know, but I would suspect this was also the case for `PersistentView`?)* So you surely don't want to create a large number of these sources. But if you're interested in event from many actors, you'll more likely tag the events and then use `eventsByTag` to get a source for all events with the given tag(s).
3. There has been some discussion around this at the time. In my own words, I'd say the use case to have a view/read side for a single actor is not a common one. To build a CQRS system based on Akka Persistence, the need for a more powerful way of consuming any set of events and processing them in arbitrary ways made the streaming queries a better choice. In the Akka team's words, the design decision was explained in [Akka Persistence on the Query Side: The Conclusion](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/akka-user/MNDc9cVG1To/blqgyC7sIRgJ).
4. I don't know the library, and even if I did, that'd be hard to say without knowing your use case, i.e. what you actually do in your receiving actor. Personally, I'm happy with `PersistenceQuery` and don't see the need to emulate `PersistentView`, especially as it's fairly easy to send the events from the stream to an actor as mentioned in 1.

Comment: by "each time", i meant each "materialization" of the stream ( with runwith/runFor/runFold , etc.) My understanding is that each materialisation will query the database and return a stream which will be different depending on when you materialise the stream. my question was about the flow of this materialization process and what it is that results into the continuous materialization of this stream for my actor which is in effect "subscribed" to it.

Comment: I have now come across `Sink.actorRef` and a mention of "resumable-streams" which I think might be related to what I am looking for. As for your suggestion of `mapAsync`, I am not sure if I understand how that would fit into the picture. again, that seems to be a flavour of materilizing a stream. What I am looking for is getting this in a loop so that the actor effectively receives all the messages coming from the said streams in its receive block and responds to them.

Comment: I don't understand why you would materialize an "eventsByPersistenceId" or "eventsByTag" multiple times. My approach would be to materialize it once and thus "subscribe" to the journal events. I corrected the answer slightly, as when I wrote "create the source" what I meant was "run/materialize the stream". 
Note that `mapAsync` does not materialize a stream, it's a way of integrating streams with actors. Added explanatory link to answer.

Comment: I see. So the actor receives all messages with the specified persistence ID, that were sent not only before the spawning of the actor, but also the ones afterwards until it dies. The stream won't be "completed" at any point. This is in contrast to how I imagined the materialisation of streams as snapshots at a given time.

Comment: I tried `events.runWith(Sink.actorRef(self, None))` in an actor and I can receive all the messages before and after the spawn of the actor. This is great, except that it doesn't have back-pressure. I also tried `mapAsync` but I am not sure if I understand the interplay of parallelism and back-pressure mechanisms very well, as plugging in large and small parallelism values results into some messages not being received by the actor. could you elaborate that or give me some links to study.

Comment: I added another link and some detail about the parallelism argument. What you're seeing with parallelism > 1 is probably not events "not being received", but received out of order.

Comment: Thanks. as for parallelism parameter, have a look at this gist: https://gist.github.com/ShahOdin/f92dcc9f8f68704bb41535ded675bd4d (it's based on this app: https://github.com/SalmaKhater/Learning-Akka/tree/84a9feb7dd530011e25796cb5f044c8b1ad63d3a/persistent-fsm%26query/src/main/scala ) for some reason, if I set parallelism to 1, I only get one `println` message printed, whereas increasing it seems to have the effect of printing the rest.

Comment: Commented on the gist: https://gist.github.com/ShahOdin/f92dcc9f8f68704bb41535ded675bd4d#gistcomment-2133630

Comment: Thanks! copy paste is a bad Idea! reading docs however is a good one! :) I think in my case, where I am only doing reads from the journal and dont really return  Futures, I should use maps. (it works) maps don't seem to have a parallelisation parameter though, although it does seem to offer back-pressure.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147708/discussion-between-shs-and-lutzh).

Comment: this is what I came up with. I think it demonstrate the points you raised and an efficient "re-implementation" of `PersistentView`.

Answer (score 0):

This [repository](https://github.com/ShahOdin/QueryView/) demoes the usage of `PersistenceQuery` and offers a very lightweight re-implementation of the Akka's deprecated `PersistentView` with the Stream API.